# How long do I have to stay in a country before I can travel into a new country during covid

Tags: international-travel, cyprus, montenegro, covid-19

I want to travel to Cyprus from a country that I need special permission during covid to enter from (Montenegro). However if you fly from Bulgaria you are able to enter Cyprus with a PCR test negative result. I am able to enter Bulgaria from Montenegro with a PCR test result. Am I able to travel to Bulgaria and then fly from there to Cyprus to get around this? And if so, how long must I stay in Bulgaria before flying to Cyprus?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: 15 days.

Quoting Cyprus Flight Pass, government website (emphasis mine):

> **Grey (Special Permission) Category**
>
> If you are traveling to the Republic of Cyprus:
>
> - from a Country categorized in the Grey (Special Permission) Category
>   (Origin Country of departure by any means of transport) or
> - **you have stayed/ lived in a  Grey (Special Permission) Category Country(ies)**
>   **within the last 14 days before your trip** to the Republic of Cyprus
>   from a Green or Orange or Red Category country or
> - you will be a passengers on an international trip to the Republic of Cyprus from a
>   Green or an Orange Category or a Red Category, via an intermediate
>   Country (ies) of the Grey (Special Permission) Category  with an
>   overnight stay
>
> according to the relevant categorization of Countries
> announced by Republic of Cyprus:
>
> - you will be under compulsory self-isolation for 14 days, according to
>   the instructions and the precautionary and self-protection measures of
>   the Ministry of Health, regardless of whether the result of the
>   COVID-19 laboratory test is negative, either at your residence or in
>   case you do not have a residence in the Republic of Cyprus, at a place
>   that will be indicated to you by the Republic of Cyprus
> - or you will be
>   under compulsory self-isolation for 7 days, in case you will repeat a
>   COVID-19 molecular test, on 7th day of my self-isolation, with a
>   negative result, at your own expenses and the result of the laboratory
>   test has been sent to the following electronic address:
>   monada@mphs.moh.gov.cy according to the instructions and the
>   precautionary and self-protection measures of the Ministry of Health.
>
> If you belong to at least one of the following Passenger Categories,
> you have the option to request the  COVID-19 test to be carried out
> upon  your arrival in the Republic of Cyprus (Laboratory tests will be
> carried out on arrival):
>
> 1. Cypriot citizens and their family members (foreign spouses and their
>    minor children).
> 2. Persons legally residing in the Republic of Cyprus.
> 3. Persons allowed to enter in the Republic of Cyprus under the Vienna
>    Convention.
> 4. Persons, with a nationality of third countries, having a special permission by the Republic of Cyprus Persons, as defined under
>    the infectious Diseases (Determination of Measures Against the Spread
>    of the COVID-19 Coronavirus disease) Decree (N.9) of 2021 as amended.

This means that if you've been in Montenegro in the 14 days prior to your arrival, you'll still need to quarantine. To avoid that, you need to not have been in any Grey country (like Montenegro) for the past 14 days.

To be clear, grey countries are all countries that are not found on the color list (green, orange, red).